# Change encoding of stdin / stdout at runtime in Python 3

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, python-3.x

In Python 3, `stdin` and `stdout` are TextIOWrappers that have an encoding and hence spit out normal strings (not bytes).

I can change the encoding that is being used with an environment variable [PYTHONIOENCODING](http://docs.python.org/py3k/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING). Is there also a way to change this in my script itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually `TextIOWrapper` *does* return bytes.  It takes a Unicode string and returns a byte string in a particular encoding.  To change `sys.stdout` to use a particular encoding in a script, here's an example:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, Apr 11 2012, 07:15:24) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print('\u5000')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\dev\python32\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u5000' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>>>> import io
>>> import io
>>> import sys
>>> sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer,encoding='utf8')
>>> print('\u5000')
σÇÇ
```

(my terminal isn't UTF-8)

`sys.stdout.buffer` accesses the raw byte stream.  You can also use the following to write to `stdout` in a particular encoding:

```
sys.stdout.buffer.write('\u5000'.encode('utf8'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Python 3.7 `TextIOWrapper` has a [`reconfigure()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper.reconfigure) method that can change stream settings, including the encoding:

```
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')
```

One caveat: You can only change the encoding of `sys.stdin` if you haven't started reading from it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible. It explicitly says in the documentation that "**If this is set before running the interpreter**, it overrides the encoding used for stdin/stdout/stderr"

also i got an error when trying to change `sys.__stdin__.encoding` saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: readonly attribute
```

EDIT: In python 2.x it was possible to change the encoding of stdin/out/err from within the script. In python 3.x it seems like you have to use `locale` (or set the environment variable from the command line before running your script).

EDIT: this might be interesting to read for you http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ideas/15313