# Make python3 default to latin-1 for a script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

TL;DR: Can I make Python 3 use anything other than unicode as default encoding for everything?

I have some scripts written in Python 3. While operating on my own files, they worked fine, because the files where encoded in utf-8 and usually using only the ASCII-compatible subset anyway.

Now I tried using the same scripts on decades-old source files and I get unicode exceptions left and right. It is entirely possible, that the files have been edited with editors assuming different encodings over the year, so the encoding of each file may differ or even be ill-defined.

If I had written my scripts in Python 2, which assumes a fixed-width encoding, everything would work fine. The parts using non-ascii characters are only in comments anyway.

In Python3 the clean solution when encodings are unknown and possibly ill-defined would be to operate only on byte-array data, but the absence of a `.format` function and the need to distinguish between bytes and str literals everywhere is both a syntactics nightmare and too time-consuming to fix across my scripts to be worthwhile.

Is it possible to change the assumed default encoding of sys.stdin, sys.stderr, and all files `open`ed without explicit encoding to a fixed-width encoding? Doing so would allow my scripts to work as "bytes in, bytes out", which would really fit my use of shell scripts better (and would ultimately be more stable).

Ideally the solution should be possible on a per-script basis and allow ignoring environment variables.

The best I could come up with based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/12823030/2075630 is

```
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.buffer, encoding="latin-1")
sys.stderr = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stderr.buffer, encoding="latin-1")
sys.stdin  = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer,  encoding="latin-1")

# To avoid changing individual `open` calls: 
open_ = open
def open(*a,**b):
    b["encoding"] = "latin-1"
    return open_(*a,**b)
```

but this causes the STDOUT and STDERR streams to be heavily buffered, which is undesirable for shell-scripts.

Comment: Why do you think this causes heavy buffering? You didn't add any buffering, you *removed the text I/O wrapper*, replacing it with another wrapper. This doesn't alter buffering behaviour.

Comment: So I would have thought. But before adding the lines, the script would produce output while running. After adding the lines, the output would come all in one piece after processing had finished. So apparently the new TextIOWrapper adds buffering.

Comment: The only buffering option `TextIOWrapper()` has is the `line_buffering` argument. Set it to `True` to send an implicit `flush()` to the underlying buffer whenever a newline is written.

Comment: Thanks, that parameter partially solved the issue (since not only `"\n"` but also `"\r"` seems to cause a flush, which is required for some status messages). You could turn that change into an answer that I could then accept (with this change it fulfills my requirements).

Comment: You can always add a `flush=True` argument to `print()` statements.

Comment: @Martijn: My intent was to find a solution that I can just drop quickly drop into an existing script, when I run into this issue during work and don't have the time to review the entire script. Also, your previous comment already was fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 doesn't assume *any* encoding. It basically operates on bytes. Read your files in binary mode and process `bytes` to go back to that mode.

You can treat the STDIO streams as binary by accessing the `.buffer` attribute:

```
bytes_from_stdin = sys.stdin.buffer.read()
sys.stdout.buffer.write(bytes_to_stdout)
```

Add `'b'` to the file mode to open files in binary mode.

Normally the codec picked for STDIO encoding / decoding is based on the current locale of your terminal where you are running the script. To switch codecs, you can switch locale in your terminal, or set one for just Python by setting the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable:

```
PYTHONIOENCODING=latin1 ./yourscript.py
```

Text files should always be opened using an explicit codec; don't rely on the system default. I'm not sure that patching out `open()` is the best path to do that though.

The buffering issue with `TextIOWrapper()` can be remedied by enabling line buffering; an implicit `buffer.flush()` call is executed every time a `\n` newline is written to the wrapper if you set `line_buffering=True`:

```
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(
    sys.stdout.buffer, encoding="latin-1", line_buffering=True)
```

Comment: Sadly, using bytes-based APIs leads to verbose code (up to python 3.4 at least there is no `bytes.format`) and a lot of refactoring (replacing string literals by bytes literals, but being careful not to replace literals where bytes is not valid). This may be a clean solution, but it is unviable for a collection of shell-scripts. Using PYTHONIOENCODING is viable, but requires either a wrapper script or introduces an obscure machine-dependent behaviour if set up as a global value. As for patching `open()`, that solution is meant to avoid refactoring affected scripts.

Comment: @kdb: did you mean to mark this as accepted and then unaccept again? Anything I can help with here?